# ctypes: How to declare a function that receives utf-8 strings?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ctypes

I am trying to make sense of the ctypes/callback documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions

My c code defines a LogFunction as:

```c
typedef void (*LogFunction)(int logLevel, const char* loggerName, const char* logMessage);
```

So my naive attempt (following the documentation) has been to expose the API using:

```py
LOGFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p)
acme_listener_configure = _lib.acme_listener_configure
acme_listener_configure.restype = None
acme_listener_configure.argtypes = [LOGFUNC]
```

However when using it (python3):

```py
def py_log_func(a, b, c):
  print("py_log_func", a, b, c)
  return

acme_listener_configure(LOGFUNC(py_log_func))
```

Here is what I see (Debian):

```
py_log_func 5 b'acme.logger.name' b'invalid input'
```

Is there a way to declare `LOGFUNC` so that conversion from `bytes` into proper `utf-8` strings is done correctly (I know the library passes utf-8 buffer in this function).

Answer (score 1):

`bytes` are how UTF-8 strings are represented.  It sounds like you want to decode the received UTF-8 byte strings to Unicode strings.  If so, then `.decode()` defaults to using `'utf8'` to decode strings:

```py
from ctypes import *

LOGFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p)
acme_listener_configure = _lib.acme_listener_configure
acme_listener_configure.argtypes = LOGFUNC,
acme_listener_configure.restype = None

@LOGFUNC
def py_log_func(a, b, c):
  print("py_log_func", a.decode(), b.decode(), c.decode())

acme_listener_configure(py_log_func)
```

Note that using `LOGFUNC` as a decorator of the callback can prevent some issues if the callback is continued to be used beyond the `.configure` function; otherwise, the `LOGFUNC(py_log_func)` object is destroyed after the function call returns.